# Multiple errors displaying php variable in html page

Tags: php, html

After grabbing a dataset from a dbtable, I am trying to loop through the results and display certain data.
What I am getting is:

1. An image place holder, but no image. F12 inspector shows class="img-responsive" ok, but src shows the whole <php statement.
2. The following lines show the <?php statements commented out <!--
3. The Button shows OK, but again the <a hfer=" shows the whole <?php echo statement.
4. $maxCols = 6, so I only want six columns across. Right now for test purposes I am limiting $rowCount to 10 records.
5. The page is testBrand.htm.php

```
type<body>
<h1>Brand</h1>
<br />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">

<?php

while($maxCol <= $maxCol && $rowCount <= $rowCount) {
    $brand      = $result['brand'];
    $prod_name  = $result['prod_name'];
    $prod_url   = $result['prod_url'];
    $image_url  = $result['image_url'];
    $price      = $result['price'];
    $sale_price = $result['sale_price'];

    str_replace('?','\?', $image_url);      // Not sure if this worked
    str_replace('$','\$', $image_url);

    echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='<?php echo $image_url' />";
    echo "<p><strong><?php $brand; ?></strong><br />";
    echo "<?php $price; ?> <?php $sale_price; ?><br />";
    echo "<?php echo $prod_name; ?></p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<a href='<?php echo $prod_url ?>' >";
    echo "<button>Buy Now</button></a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "&nbsp ";

    $rowCount--;
    if($rowCount == 40){    // Test only
        break;
    }

    if ($maxCol-- == 0) {
        echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<div col-sm-3>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<div col-sm-3>";
    }
}

?>
```

I have seen many problems similar to this listed here and tried some of those solutions, but I think there is a combined effect messing things up here.

Would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: You don't put `<?php` into `echo` statements. Just echo the variable: `echo $price;`

Comment: I think you're confusing this with `<strong><?php echo $brand; ?></strong>` when you're already outside of `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

i see that you didn't closed the php tag at the image,

```
<?php echo $image_url ?> '
```

but thats not a good approach, use this instead,

```
echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='".$image_url."' />";
```

thats even better, imagine your query outputs to results.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($results as $result){
    $i++;
    $brand      = $result['brand'];
    $prod_name  = $result['prod_name'];
    $prod_url   = $result['prod_url'];
    $image_url  = $result['image_url'];
    $price      = $result['price'];
    $sale_price = $result['sale_price'];

    $image_url  = str_replace('?','\?', $image_url); // you need to define the output to a variable
    $image_url = str_replace('$','\$', $image_url);

    echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='".$image_url."' />
    <p><strong>".$brand."</strong><br />"
    .$price. " ".$sale_price."<br />"
    .$prod_name."</p>
     </div>
     <div>
        <a href='".$prod_url."' >
        <button>Buy Now</button></a>
     </div>&nbsp";

    if($i == 40){
        break;
    }
}

//Close your div or table etc. here
```

also if you are making a str_replace, remember to define the output to a variable to use it later, or it will lost in the empty space of php :)

keep practicing and you will be better